# How to resolve Java.lang.numberformatexception: empty string

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a utility function which convert `parseDouble` value to string.

```java
public static BigDecimal setValue(Object o) {
  BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(0);
  if(o!= Null){
    value=BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(o.toString()));
  }
  return value;
}
```

I have tried with `(o!=null && !isEmpty(o))` and `(o!="" && o!=null)` but it is still throwing same error.

Transaction amount which is processing this utility function contains empty value.

Comment: Apparently the empty thing is the result of `o.toString()` .

Comment: why do you convert to a double first?

Comment: Some *general* comments: (1) parsing a string to a double sometimes results in a different value than you would get from parsing a `BigDecimal` directly from a string due to representation inaccuracies. `BigDecimal`'s big reason for existence (IMHO) is to represent values (from a string) that can NOT be accurately represented with a `double`. So parsing to a `double` first removes its usefulness, you'd be better of just using `double`s (but I guess you do want the accuracy). So rather parse directly from a string (using `new BigDecimal()`, and catching the `NumberFormatException`).

Comment: (2) Change the input parameter accordingly. If you want to cater for `Integer` and `Double` together with `String`, rather use bounded generics (and typechecking logic). Using a raw `Object` is usually suspect... (3) instead of `new BigDecimal(0)`, use `BigDecimal.ZERO` - it's quicker at runtime (for what it's worth). Also `ONE` and `TEN` are available. (4) One should generally use the `.equals()` method to compare `Object`'s values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I don't understand why you are taking object type as an input, however to resolve your issue you can do something like this. But I would strongly advice you to change the method signature it is misleading.

```
public static BigDecimal setValue(Object o) {
    var value = new BigDecimal(0);
    if (o != null) {
        if(o instanceof String) {
            if (((String) o).trim().length()>0) {
                value = new BigDecimal((String) o);
            }
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would change the method signature to BigDecimal setValue(String s). Your null check and length check code should then work fine.
Also the method name is misleading. The method does not set anything. Something like convertToBigDecimal would be clearer.